# jQuery help with .each function

Tags: javascript, jquery

**UPDATE 4:**

This is what I have at the moment:

```
var $elements = $('.dropdown');
var $lastElement = $elements.last();

$elements.slice(0, -1).each(function() {
    $(this).css('left', $(this).prev.position().left);
});

var $prev = $lastElement.prev();
$lastElement.css('left', $prev.position().left - ($prev.outerWidth() - $lastElement.outerWidth()));
```

Which is giving me:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object function (d,e){var f=c.map(this,b,d);Za.test(a)||(e=d);if(e&&typeof e==="string")f=c.filter(e,f);f=this.length>1?c.unique(f):f;if((this.length>1||ab.test(e))&&$a.test(a))f=f.reverse();return this.pushStack(f,a,bb.call(arguments).join(","))} has no method 'position'
$.ajax.success homepage.htm:138
c.b.extend.each jquery.min.js:33
c.b.fn.b.each jquery.min.js:26
$.ajax.success homepage.htm:137
c.extend.handleSuccess jquery.min.js:142
c.extend.ajax.L.w.onreadystatechange jquery.min.js:141
```

So something in the above script does not have a position method.

---

**UPDATE 3:**

This is what I have at the moment:

var $elements = $('.dropdown');
var $lastElement = $elements.last();

$elements.slice(0, -1).each(function() {
    $(this).css('left', $(this).prev.position().left);
});

var $prev = $lastElement.prev();
$lastElement.css('left', $prev.position().left - ($prev.outerWidth() - $lastElement.outerWidth()));

It's giving me a `function required` error.  When I take out the last 2 lines, the error disappears, but the problem does not get solved.

---

**UPDATE 2:**

This is the HTML structure:

```
<div class="settings"><span id="spanSettings">Settings ▼</span></div>
<div class="dropdown">
    <a href="edit_profile.aspx"><div class="item"><div class="icon" style="background-image: url('http://intranet/img/profile_icon.png');"></div> Edit profile</div></a>
    <a href="manage_tabs.aspx"><div class="item"><div class="icon" style="background-image: url('http://intranet/img/tabs_icon.png');"></div> Tab settings</div></a>
</div>
```

---

**UPDATE 1:**

With: `$(this).css('left', $(this).prev().position().left);`

I get [image 1](https://docs.google.com/leaf?id=0B1-CN3-vjUYvOGM1OTg2M2ItOWI2Yi00N2E4LWE4YWMtOGZmZjhmODhhYjIw&hl=en_US):

with: `$(this).css('right', $(this).prev().position().right);`

I get [image 2](https://docs.google.com/leaf?id=0B1-CN3-vjUYvOWQzYTk3ZWQtOGI3Yy00Mzc3LWIwMmItZDZlOWNmZjQ3YmIw&hl=en_US) :

I am after [image 3](https://docs.google.com/leaf?id=0B1-CN3-vjUYvYTY5ZGMxMzMtZTI4MS00M2ExLTk2YWEtNmRjMTlkZTk3NjZk&hl=en_US):

^ Image 3 is photoshopped.

---

**ORIGINAL QUESTION:**

I have the following script which changes the position of any html element which has the class `dropdown`

```
$('.dropdown').each(function() {
    $(this).css('left', $(this).prev().position().left);
});
```

How do I modify this so it changes all the `dropdown`'s to left based on the parent, except the last one, which should be `right` aligned with the parents right position?

If that is not possible, how do I independently change their positions?  instead of using the `each` function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do:

```
var $elements = $('.dropdown'),
    $lastElement = $elements.last();

$elements.slice(0, -1).each(function() {
    $(this).css('left', $(this).prev().position().left);
});

$lastElement.css('right', $lastElement.prev().position().right);
```

**Update:** to align it as you showed in the picture (I assume it is about the last element), you could try:

```
var $prev = $lastElement.prev();
$lastElement.css('left', $prev.position().left - ($prev.outerWidth() - $lastElement.outerWidth()));
```

Comment: This gives me a squashed dropdown for some reason.  I think maybe I am not explaining what I am after properly.  Basically, the left of all dropdowns should be aligned with the left of their parent.  However, the last dropdown, its right needs to be aligned with the right if it's parent.

Comment: @oshirowanen: Oh parent... then use `parent` instead of `prev`... updated. `prev` gives you the previous sibling...

Comment: Sounds like prev is what I am supposed to be using.  Please see update 1 in original question as I don't think I am explaining the problem properly.  I have uploaded images to show you exactly what I mean.

Comment: @oshirowanen: I think you'd also have to post the HTML structure. Even better if you can provide a http://jsfiddle.net/ demo to play with.

Comment: I've added update 2, which shows the HTML of the structure in question.

Comment: @oshirowanen: Well, I forgot a closing bracket ;) Fixed.

Comment: Getting a `Function expected` error message.  However, it seems to be aligning with the span within the div.  It should be aligning with the top most div in the html I have posted above.

Comment: @oshirowanen: I don't know where this error could come from. It should not be from my code actually. But I'm sure you can figure it out. You might have to pass `true` to `outerWidth`. I cannot know how the elements are styled. Have a look at the documentation: http://api.jquery.com/outerWidth/

Comment: @oshirowanen: Uh I see now... It should be `$prev.position()`, not `$prev().position()`... but I'd expect that you can debug code on your own too ;)

Comment: @oshirowanen: You changed too much of the script. I never said you have to change `$(this).prev()`. I was always only talking about the last element thing. Honestly, don't just copy and paste code and then just "it's not working". Try to understand the code and fix minor errors on your own. It seems you don't even try to.

Comment: I have reverted back to your original script update, and the errors have gone, but it is still not lining up properly.  The right side of the dropdown goes too far to the left, i.e. it is not lining up with with the right of the div which activates it.  I can see what the script is doing.  What I don't understand is why it is not working.

Comment: @oshirowanen: It would be easier to help if you set up a http://jsfiddle.net/ demo. I don't which styles are applied to the elements. If you create a demo and can try different things. This way I more or less have to guess what might work.

Answer (score 1):

You could write a quick plugin for this:

```
$.fn.eachLast = function(fn, fnLast) {
  return this.slice(0, -1).each(fn).end().last().each(fnLast).end();
}

$('.dropdown').eachLast(
  function() { // will be executed for all elements in the collection except the last one
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.css('left', $this.parent().position().left);
  },
  function() { // will only be executed for the last element in the collection
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.css('right', $this.prev().position().right);
  }
);
```

Alternatively, you could do something like this:

```
var $lastElement = $('.dropdown').slice(0, -1).each(function() {
  var $this = $(this);
  $this.css('left', $this.prev().position().left);
}).end().last();

$lastElement.css('right', $lastElement.parent().position().right);

// …or even…

var $lastElement = $('.dropdown').slice(0, -1).each(function() {
  var $this = $(this);
  $this.css($this.parent().position());
}).end().last();

$lastElement.css($lastElement.prev().position());
```

Comment: Please see update 1 in original question as I don't think I am explaining the problem properly.  I have uploaded images to show you exactly what I mean.